# System.IO.FileLoadException loading Facebook assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, assemblies

I'm having the following code that does not compile:

```
{
    private static FacebookWrapper.FacebookService m_FacebookService;
    User m_LoggedInUser;

    public void LoginToFBApp(FacebookWrapper.FacebookService i_FacebookService)
    {
        LoginResult result = FacebookWrapper.FacebookService.Login("192940970765612",
            new string[]
            {
                "user_about_me", "friends_about_me", "publish_stream"
                //,
                //"user_activities", "friends_activities",
                //"user_birthday", "friends_birthday",
                //"user_checkins", "friends_checkins",
                //"user_education_history", "friends_education_history",
                //"user_events", "friends_events",
                //"user_groups" , "friends_groups",
                //"user_hometown", "friends_hometown",
                //"user_interests", "friends_interests",
                //"user_likes", "friends_likes",
                //"user_location", "friends_location",
                //"user_notes", "friends_notes",
                //"user_online_presence", "friends_online_presence",
                //"user_photo_video_tags", "friends_photo_video_tags",
                //"user_photos", "friends_photos",
                //"user_photos", "friends_photos",
                //"user_relationships", "friends_relationships",
                //"user_relationship_details","friends_relationship_details",
                //"user_religion_politics","friends_religion_politics",
                //"user_status", "friends_status",
                //"user_videos", "friends_videos",
                //"user_website", "friends_website",
                //"user_work_history", "friends_work_history",
                //"email",
                //"read_friendlists",
                //"read_insights",
                //"read_mailbox",
                //"read_requests",
                //"read_stream",
                //"xmpp_login",

                //"create_event",
                //"rsvp_event",
                //"sms",
                //"publish_checkins",
                //"manage_friendlists",
                //"manage_pages",

                //"offline_access"
            },
            false);
    }
```

}

I'm using an DLL that I was given,in wich is helping to perform Login to facebook account.            When activating my program,the program is trying to connect to facebook,but I'm getting the exeption with the text that is shown in the headline of this message.
Extra information appears in the exeption:

```
  Could not load file or assembly 'Facebook, Version=5.0.50.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=58cb4f2111d1e6de' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I don't understand where exactly is the problem....

Comment: Where did you get the assembly from? It sounds like it's broken, basically...

Comment: That or it depends on something else, which you do'nt seem to have

Comment: I get this message on runing time,when I step into the function that responsible for login. What could be broken?